# Reading/writing variables line per line from/to a text file? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, codeblocks

I want to *make* a text file as follows:

```
car = "big"
couse = "small"
quality = 0
apple = "red"
```

And then read from it.. So that `string car = "what";` and `int quality = 1;` change into `"big"` and `0`.

I have no idea how to go about this, since I'm fairly new to C++, and even though I'm certain that this question has been asked a lot before, I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or possibly [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)).

Comment: If this is a config file of some sort, you can use GetPrivateProfileString/WritePrivateProfileString:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the basis of [I/O with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

The idea is to load a file, read it line by line and then parse the lines in order to retreive your informations.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Djon, how about some pseudo-code?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // open file
   // loop begin
      // read in file, storing lines in an array (or vector) of strings
   // loop end
   // parse lines, to find the ones you want
   // replace data in lines as you like
   // delete original file
   // create new version of file, with data in string vector 
   // close the file
   // done!
}
```

Following this algorithm, you should be able to solve your issue.